# Restarting a Gravity Flow workflow after editing a field with GravityEdit : For Multiple Forms

Tags: php, if-statement, gravity-forms-plugin

I have this code from [GravityEdit](https://docs.gravitykit.com/article/864-how-to-log-the-user-that-modified-the-entry) that triggers & updates whoever edited a Gravity Form with the user name.

As per their documentation I can currently place one form.(i.e form name & form ID)

`add_filter( 'gravityview-inline-edit/entry-updated', 'gravityedit_custom_who_changed', 10, 5 );

function gravityedit_custom_who_changed( $update_result, $entry = array(), $form_id = 0, $gf_field = null, $original_entry = array() ) {

```
if ( 124 !== (int) $form_id ) { // replace 124 with your form ID
    return $update_result;
}

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( ! ( $current_user instanceof WP_User ) ) {
    return $update_result;
}

$field_id = 3; // replace 3 with the ID of the field you want to store the username

$update_result = GFAPI::update_entry_field( $entry['id'], $field_id, $current_user->user_login );

return $update_result;
```

}`

Can anyone assist on how I can add a second form i.e another form & ID (e.g form 25 form id 3)?

(I'm in Marketing R&D pardon my noobness in PHP)

Thanks!

Getting "cannot redeclare" when I duplicate the code in functions.php

Answer (score 0):

In an "if" statement, you can use || for the logical operator "or":

'if ( 124 !== (int) $form_id )' can be changed to:

```
if ( 124 !== (int) $form_id || 25 !== (int) $form_id ){
   return $update_result;
}
```